# Future which never completes

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

Having a need to test some methods which can cause a timeout, I want to create a helper function for that. It should return a `Future` that **never** completes:

```
def neverCompletes[T]: Future[T] = { ... }
```

But I wonder, how can I do that? I could that like the following:

```
def neverCompletes[T]: Future[T] = {
  val p = Promise[T]()
  future {
    while(true) { }
  } onComplete {
    case x => 
      p complete x // needed?
      println("something went wrong!!!") // something is wrong...
  }

  p.future
}
```

But there should be a better way to achieve that out there. I also not sure whether `p complete x // needed?` is needed there.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update:**

In Scala 2.12 there will be a method `Future.never` that returns a future that never completes.

---

Easy thing. Just create a `Promise` and return its `Future` without ever completing it:

```
def neverCompletes[T]: Future[T] = Promise[T].future
```

Comment: I'm curious, it there any way to do the same but without using Promise?

Comment: No, a future always has a promise as counterpart. Actually it even is the same object: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L21